# How do I organise pure QML projects for reusability?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qmake

I have [a QML project](https://gitlab.com/detly/MyComponent/tree/44571f968b6174aaee64ad91308b106fddc5cafe) that works fine when it's all in the same directory. There's a `main.qml` with a `main.cpp` containing the usual:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

There is also my custom component, in pure QML, `MyComponent.qml`.

When it is contained within a single project, it works perfectly. But now I want to think about reusability.

I want to have separate `main()`s for the demo (what's there now), unit testing and usability testing. I want to be able to run these independently of each other.

I also want to use `MyComponent.qml` *without* any of these `main()`s in other projects (that's the whole point!).

I am not too hung up on the structure here, I just want the demo code to be separate from the widget code and to have a reusable widget.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

I've read [How to package custom controls in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597690/how-to-package-custom-controls-in-qml)
 but the answer is light on detail. I can create the appropriate files for an [Identified Module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html), but how do my separate projects actually access and incorporate them?

I tried to arrange things as sub-projects, but didn't get very far. If I create a `widget` sub-project as a library project, I have this `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = lib

TARGET = widget-lib

QT += core quick qml
CONFIG += c++11 plugin

DISTFILES += \
    MyComponent.qml
```

The project then fails to build because there's no actual library or entry point or, in fact, any code at all:

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __DllMainCRTStartup@12
```

debug\widget-lib.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

The only other project type on offer in Qt Creator is a QML/C++ plugin, but since I have no C++ code in my actual component, that doesn't seem applicable.

Adding the `MyComponent.qml` file to a `demo` sub-project also fails. With this QRC file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>../widget/MyComponent.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

...the built demo project can't find `MyComponent.qml` because `../widget/` doesn't exist in the build output path.

Adding the `widget` sub-project as a library also fails because there's no actual shared library to link against, so `demo` can't be built.

I've read [Module Definition qmldir Files](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html), but it's all about how to create the file, and has nothing on how to use it.

How do I actually *reuse* a "reusable QML component"? How do I use the component itself in other projects, or have multiple mini-projects for testing the component itself? And how do I achieve this without just copy-pasting the component QML file into every project that needs it?

Comment: If I understand well your question you just want to *package* of QML widgets. I don't know how to do that, but do you really need a specific lib ? I don't see the purpose of your organization. What is the other project ? The other `main.cpp` ?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are a looking for : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html

Comment: @ymoreau At this point, I don't have another one, but I'd like to have unit tests and usability tests as well, which both require separate `main()`s. I also intend to use the control in real applications, of which there will be many.

Comment: I read the section on `qmldir` files, I wrote one, but... now what? It doesn't do anything for the projects that depend upon the control.

Comment: It *almost* looks like [*Other Project > Qt Quick UI Prototype*](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/quick-projects.html) is what I need here but `*drumroll*` it cannot be created as a subproject!

Comment: I guess it does not make sense for QMake to create a subproject which is just a set of QML files. Can't you just create your QRC for this package and include it in the different projects you need ? Why create a subproject for this ?

Comment: @ymoreau Why do it for C++ code?

Comment: @ymoreau I mean, it's possible, sure. But copy-pasting source files separately into the tree of every project that need them is prone to things getting out of sync and becoming hard to track. I had expected that QML could be packaged and shared like many other scripting languages, but if it's not designed for it, it is what it is.

Comment: C++ code must be compiled so it can be convenient to only link to binaries of a lib. QML on the other hand, you just need one import path to use it directly. And QML has some ways to be packaged, just not as a subproject, it does not mean you need to copy-paste any file. We pointed out some options here in the comments, have you tried anything ?

Comment: @ymoreau Good point re C++. But I've read all the resources you've suggested, I just don't understand how they allow me to share a single QML component between multiple projects. I wrote a `qmldir` file... how does eg. the unit test project use this file? I can edit a project's QRC file to point to the component's directory, but the resulting binary still errors out because it can't find the QML file. How does it fit together?

Comment: (I am definitely dreading the day when I actually *do* need a QML component backed by some C++ code, because that just seems completely off the map for Qt Creator or QMake. But that's getting O/T.)

Comment: To spell it out, [here's an example](https://gitlab.com/detly/MyComponent) of a super simple QML project. How do I turn this into something that (a) has separate unit test, usability test and demo projects and (b) can be used by another application, in a totally separate project from this one?

Comment: @ymoreau I've changed the question a bit to make it more about what I want to achieve. The subproject structure etc. was where the docs led me, but not necessarily the best approach.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any answer to give there. I thought that including a simple QRC could do the trick, but maybe this does not work with sibling-directories and sub-projects. I don't have any other idea right now.

Comment: @ymoreau No worries, I'll keep experimenting. Maybe I need to re-read the QRC docs and try that again.

Comment: @detly I have a similar problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @QutabQazi unfortunately not, the project I was using it for was cut short so I never had to find a solution.